# Не работает php include

Tags: php, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

Купил хост за 0.5$. PHP поддерживает.
Не работает `include`
В `index.html` в теге `body` указал

```
<?php include('php/test.php'); ?>
```

в `test.php`

```
<p>Testing string</p>
```

Почему не выводится сообщение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно прописать не относительный путь к подпапке, а абсолютный путь. Причём не от корня сайта, а от корня хостинга. На Мастерхосте это выглядит так:

```
include_once '/home/uXXXXX/mysite.ru/www/php/test.php';
```

**Обновление из комментариев к ответу**

- Если index.html в index.php переименовать, что покажет?
- Заработало. А почему?
- HTML - это разметка страницы, а PHP - скрипт. Поэтому php-файлы умеют инклюдить друг друга, а для html-страницы php-строка с инклюдом - пустой звук. Чинится либо строгим соблюдением расширения, либо настройкой сервера. Я посоветовал поменять расширение, и это помогло. Сосед посоветовал поменять настройки, чтобы html-страницы обрабатывались как php-скрипты. Почему его совет не помог, надо разбираться. Совет то тоже правильный.

Comment: не работает....

Comment: @Herrgott test.php сам по себе что показывает? Если index.html в index.php переименовать, что покажет?

Comment: Вот, теперь работает, спасибо. А почему так?

Comment: @Herrgott Я немного запутался в двух параллельных диалогах.... Что в итоге сделали? После чего заработало?

Comment: после переименования в `index.php`

Comment: @Herrgott HTML - это разметка страницы, а PHP - скрипт. Поэтому php-файлы умеют инклюдить друг друга, а для html-страницы php-строка с инклюдом - пустой звук. Чинится либо строгим соблюдением расширения, либо настройкой сервера. Я посоветовал поменять расширение, и это помогло. Сосед посоветовал поменять настройки, чтобы html-страницы обрабатывались как php-скрипты.  Почему его совет не помог, надо разбираться. Совет то тоже правильный.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от настройки веб-сервера. На сколько я понимаю у Вас веб-сервер игнорирует php-код, который вставленный в html-код и выводит его как обычный текст.

Попробуйте создать файл с именем: `.htaccess`
И внести в него следующую строку:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .shtml .htm
```

Comment: Он вообще ничего не выводит. Просто чистая страница

Comment: Исходный код страницы смотрели ?

Comment: смотрел через dragonfly opera, `php` функция отмечена как <--<?php .... ?> ->

Comment: Добавил, не работает

Comment: `Он вообще ничего не выводит. Просто чистая страница` Как Вы тогда определили, что не работает именно инклуд? Что будет, если вместо инклуда сделать `echo "test"` ?

Comment: @ReinRaus, ну я написал сразу `include` и на нем зациклился. С php знаком 40 минут. Раньше не мог настроить локальный сервер, а тут такая возможность подвернулась

Comment: @ReinRaus, поэтому я просто предположил и обратился к спецам по этой теме

Comment: Странный у Вас вопрос, звучит как "Почему не работает php-вставка в html-коде", а решение проблемы находите совсем другое, которое должны были знать т.к. создали файл test.php еще в самом начале.

Comment: Но Вы сделали неверный вывод- проблема не в инклуде и Вы изначально вводите своим вопросом в заблуждение. Попробуйте создать файл `index.php` и в нем указать `<HTML><BODY>test</BODY></HTML>`, начните выявлять проблему с простого.

Comment: @ReinRaus проблема у него уже решена, сосед подсказал :)

Comment: @ReinRaus Если честно, то я пока не очень разбираюсь в структуре использования php. Я думал что это нечто вроде JavaScript, только для веб-сервера и с подставкой html-кода в нужное место (Фактически это так и есть). Это вот то же самое что писать на Java, а потом резко переключиться на Ассемблер

Comment: @Yukio @Hengout А если вот такую строку добавить в `.htaccess`, то index.html заработает? Проверьте, пожалуйста. `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Comment: @GlebKemarsky нет

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky: Да, работает.

Comment: @Herrgott у Вас скорей всего веб-сервер не использует .htaccess, поэтому и не работает (все зависит от хостера). Во всяком случае - это и правильно (что php-вставки в html-коде не работают) на мой взгляд - их делать не очень хорошая идея.

Comment: @Herrgott Увидел слова про локальный сервер. [Вот здесь](http://citforum.ru/internet/articles/apache_perl.shtml#cont4) велят в файл конфигурации Apache conf/mime.types добавить строку `application/x-httpd-php3 phtml php3 php`. А вместе с html получится `application/x-httpd-php3 phtml php3 php html htm`. Попробуете?

Comment: @Yukio Спасибо. Вы на локальном сервере или на хостинге?

Comment: @Gleb Kemarsky проверял на локальном (пришлось искать конфиг на включение .htaccess т.к. по дефолту он у меня был выключен), а так есть vps (но тут + в том, что есть полный доступ к серверу), там вроде тоже самое (давно смотрел).

Comment: @Yukio Спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: @GlebKemarsky .htaccess используется по дефолту. Он уже был в корневой папке сайта. И там была прописана кастомная 404